# First Day of Week is set to Sunday instead of Monday in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, week-number

I have the following query:

```
SELECT forecastDate, to_char(to_date(forecastDate),'WW') AS WEEK_NUMBER
FROM ACT_FORECAST
```

Which give me this result :

```
forecastDate | WEEK_NUMBER
14/07/2017     28
15/07/2017     28
16/07/2017     29
```

But in my region the week start on Monday, I should have 28 for the 16/07/2017.

The NLS_TERRITORY value of my DB is 'France'.

I tried multiple things but nothing worked.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You might find your answer here:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48256816/oracle-change-start-day-of-week-tuesday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48256816/oracle-change-start-day-of-week-tuesday)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reason is the format `WW` where [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212) says:

> **WW**
>
> Week of year (1-53) where week 1 starts on the first day of the year
>   and continues to the seventh day of the year.

Luckily on ISO-8601 the first day of week is also Monday, so you can use

```
SELECT forecastDate, to_char(to_date(forecastDate),'IW') AS WEEK_NUMBER
FROM ACT_FORECAST
```

> **IW**
>
> Calendar week of year (1-52 or 1-53), as defined by the ISO 8601
>   standard.
>
> - A calendar week starts on Monday.
> - The first calendar week of the year includes January 4.
> - The first calendar week of the year may include December 29, 30 and 31.
> - The last calendar week of the year may include January 1, 2, and 3.

And btw, you should change the data type of column `forecastDate` to `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: Found it a few seconds before you posted your answer ;) Thanks for the help